# ModuleNotFoundError in Python project

Tags: python, structure, python-import, python-module, directory-structure

I have the following project structure in Python (the ... means I have n crawler_.py files).

```
project
├── crawlers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── crawler_1.py
│   ├── crawler_2.py
│   ...
│   ├── crawler_n.py
│   └── useful_functions.py
├── main.py
└── __init__.py
```

I need to import all crawlers from crawler into main, so I use this.

```
# main.py
from crawlers import crawler_1
from crawlers import crawler_2
...
from crawlers import crawler_n
```

But I also need `useful_functions.py` inside all crawler_.py files, so I use this in each one.

```
# crawler_.py
import useful_functions
```

But when I ran `main.py` I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'useful_functions'` when it tried to import crawler_1.

So I tried the following

```
# crawler_.py
from crawlers import useful_functions
```

And it works when I run `main.py`. The problem is that I might want run only one of the crawler_.py directly. Using this last import statement, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crawlers'`. Not sure how to address this problem, if there's something inside the code I should adjust or if the structure that I'm using is fundamentally wrong (I'm perfectly okay with adjusting the project structure).

Comment: Have you tried with a relative import `from . import useful_functions` in the `crawler.py`?

Comment: I had not. Just tried and got `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` when running the `crawler.py`

Comment: Nah that won't work

Comment: Try `from project.crawlers import useful_functions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this inside the `crawler_n.py`

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import useful_functions
else:
    import crawlers.useful_functions as useful_functions
```

`__name__ == '__main__'` checks if the module is called or is imported and thus makes the imports accordingly.

Comment: i think the reason why for that is the `pythonpath` variable

Comment: Reason for what?

Comment: for not resolving the import / that this if else has to happen

Comment: yeah maybe, but it's a pain to set `$PYTHONPATH` every single time

Comment: agree

was just additional information to your answer